# np.interp returning a constant array

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

For some reason, I'm going crazy over something that I've used before, but it has never given me this issue.

What might be wrong? It keeps giving me a constant array, while that definitely shouldn't be the case.

```
r0 = np.linspace(2, 215, 1000)
f = 8.9*np.sqrt(4.8e9/(r0**14) + 3e8/(r0**6) + 1.4e6/(r0**2.3))
ds = np.array([3950, 1837, 1347, 900])
np.interp(ds, f, r0)
```

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.interp` expects the known x-coordinates (i.e. the second argument, i.e. your `f`) to be monotonically increasing.

As the [documentation states](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html):

> The x-coordinate sequence is expected to be increasing, but this is not explicitly enforced. However, if the sequence xp is non-increasing, interpolation results are meaningless.

You have `r0` (the known y-coordinates) as an increasing sequence, but `f` (the known x-coordinates) as a decreasing sequence.

You should be able to get your desired results just by reversing `r0` (so that consequently `f` is reversed too):

```
import numpy as np
r0 = np.linspace(215, 2, 1000)  # Reversed endpoints compared to original
f = 8.9*np.sqrt(4.8e9/(r0**14) + 3e8/(r0**6) + 1.4e6/(r0**2.3))
ds = np.array([3950, 1837, 1347, 900])
print(np.interp(ds, f, r0))
```

which gives:

```
[3.65932599 5.34470808 6.49802343 8.7453899 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that it is voluntarily that your computed `f` from `r0` but then are using interp to compute `r0` like values from `f` like values. In other words, that you are tying to estimate the reverse function of `r0 → 8.9*np.sqrt(4.8e9/(r0**14) + 3e8/(r0**6) + 1.4e6/(r0**2.3))`.

The problem with that, is that `interp` assumes that the `x` part is sorted ascending. Like it is most of the time, when you `np.interp(somevalues, np.linspace(0,1,100), func(np.linspace(0,1,100))`

Here, apparently, the function you are trying to reverse is monotonous (it appears so at least) and decreasing. So your f is sorted, but descending.

Just reverse both arrays

```
np.interp(ds, f[::-1], r0[::-1])
```